# build libcurl with windows with HTTP2 support

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, libcurl

I am trying to install libcurl with HTTP2 support through microsoft visual build tools. It looks like, using ubuntu, you do --with-http2=path/to-nghttp2. But i can not perform that command, and i do not know the equivalent in windows. I have nghttp2 installed already as well as openssl. Where in the native build tools do i insert the command that tells libcurl to build with http2 support?

trying this does not work `nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static vc=16 debug=no DUSE_NGHTTP2=OFF`. The library builds but does not allow for http2 requests. When using the curl cli, it does not give me an error code of 1) unsuppored protocol after using this option but will not use HTTP2. Have also tried DUSE_NGHTTP2=ON

````
C:\Users\ball\Desktop\curl\curl-7.79.1\winbuild>nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static vc=16 debug=no MACHINE=x64 WITH_NGHTTP2=static NGHTTP2_PATH="C:\\Users\\ball\\Desktop\\nghttp2\\nghttp2-1.45.1\\lib\\includes\\"

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.29.30133.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

configuration name: libcurl-vc16-x64-release-static-ipv6-sspi-schannel-nghttp2-static
        cl /O2 /DNDEBUG /MT /DCURL_STATICLIB /I. /I ../lib /I../include /nologo /W4 /EHsc /DWIN32 /FD /c /DBUILDING_LIBCURL  /DUSE_WIN32_IDN /DWANT_IDN_PROTOTYPES  /DUSE_IPV6  /DUSE_WINDOWS_SSPI /DUSE_SCHANNEL /DUSE_NGHTTP2 /DNGHTTP2_STATICLIB /I"C:\\Users\\ball\\Desktop\\nghttp2\\nghttp2-1.45.1\\lib\\includes\\include" /Fo"..\builds\libcurl-vc16-x64-release-static-ipv6-sspi-schannel-nghttp2-static-obj-lib/altsvc.obj"  ..\lib\altsvc.c
altsvc.c
C:\Users\ball\Desktop\curl\curl-7.79.1\lib\http.h(38): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'nghttp2/nghttp2.h': No such file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

C:\Users\ball\Desktop\curl\curl-7.79.1\winbuild>```
````

I have tried with single blackslashes as well and no qoutes... I can confirm that folder and file is there and in this path: C:\Users\ball\Desktop\nghttp2\nghttp2-1.45.1\lib\includes\nghttp2\nghttp2.h

Answer (score 0):

CMake option is `-DUSE_NGHTTP2=ON`.

Nmake option is `WITH_NGHTTP2=dll` or `WITH_NGHTTP2=static`.

```
nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static vc=16 debug=no WITH_NGHTTP2=dll
```

Comment: see updated answer @S.M.

Comment: I don't know what are you doing. curl does not have Makefile.vc in the sources.

Comment: as stated, i am using mc build tools which implies im on windows. you can find Makefile.vc in the winbuild folder of 'curl_version'

Comment: @noah Thanks, I was never interested in the winbind directory. So, you know it, why do you not follow the [README.md](https://github.com/curl/curl/tree/master/winbuild#readme) there?

Comment: please see upated answer

Comment: Report the bug to curl. nghttp2 does not have include but has includes in lib.

Comment: i eventually got it

Comment: What did you do to resolve this?